# Can I store a pair of keys on iOS secure element?

Tags: key-management, ios, objective-c

I would like to know if I can use the iPhone's secure element to store a pair of keys. I need to store them in the safest emplacement, and I can't think of a better one than the secure element.

Comment: You probably mean the secure enclave. The secure element just handles payments and is not accessible to developers.

Comment: No I meant the secure element, but as you said it's not accessible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by setting `kSecAttrTokenID` to `kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave` when generating the key. According to the documentation (which consists of some comments in `SecItem.h`), the only kinds of keys the secure enclave can store are elliptic curve secp256r1 keys. You can't put RSA keys there, for example.

Comment: Thank you very much Wim for your help, I think that I'll stick with the keychain for my app.

Answer (score 2):

The secure element is not exposed to developers, and likely requires a custom entitlement in the App Store / App review process that isn't given out

Comment: Thank you for your help Cristo, I spent too much time searching in Apple's documentation but in vain. I just needed a confirmation before giving up.

Comment: My answer is incorrect. Please see the answer about kSecAttrTokenIDSecureEnclave.